# What is an alternative to using backticks in separating namespaces from function names?

Tags: syntax

What is an alternative to the backtick (`` ` ``) in separating the namespace from the function name?

Can the function be called without using this symbol? I think in early versions of Mathematica one could use `::` but it does not seem to work now.

Comment: You remember wrongly. `::` (`MessageName[]`) was always intended for messages, and the backtick was always intended to delimit a context and a function from that context. What exactly is your problem with the backtick?

Comment: @j.m On an iPhone/iPad entering a backtick is rather time consuming. So, editing code here on MMA.SE containing a context path is extremely annoying. Other than that, I can't think of a reason for wanting to replace the backtick.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries maybe some write mma code on iPads?

Comment: @acl Wolfram is [rumored to develop a iPad implementation](http://www.reddit.com/r/IAmA/comments/tmutz/stephen_wolfram_nks_10th_anniversary/c4nzq2r). I hope they include the W|A keyboard, as my experience with backticking code on an iPad has lead to quite some curses.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries most likely a reader...

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Relevant: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133673

Comment: @R.M yeah, I know the procedure. Problem is it takes about 5 seconds to obtain a single backtick that way. If I have to type this: ``path`name` `` in MarkDown I have to do this 6 times. Debilitating!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's your alternative:

```
test`foo[x_] := x^2 (* original function in test` context *)
ToExpression["test" <> FromCharacterCode[96] <> "foo"][x] (* Look ma! No backticks! *)
(* x^2 *)
```

Comment: Even more baroque: `ToExpression["test" <> "\\[" <> "RawBackquote" <> "]" <> "foo"][x]`

Comment: @J.M. `ToExpression[
  "test" <> Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPCmZkYGBIAAAM0wH5"] <> "foo"][x]`

Comment: That ain't baroque; that's grotesque. ;)

Comment: @J.M. if it ain't baroque, don't fix it!

Comment: `ToExpression[
 TextRecognize@
  Rasterize[
   Style[Row[{"test", "\[NegativeVeryThinSpace]", 
      Rotate[",", Pi/2, {0, 1.5}], "f"}], FontSize -> 40]]][x]`

Comment: @Rojo It doesn't give the same thing though... it returns `(f text)[x]` for me. This was actually the next thing I wanted to try (had JM continued), but I couldn't get `TextRecognize` to recognize a backtick in an image. And then I had to sleep...

Comment: RM, it works for me... It returns that if I remove the negative space however, hehe